# Show links (my quick) from my site on Intranet

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, my-site, hyperlink, intranet

On my site, the users can add private links `/_layouts/15/MyQuickLinks.aspx` on their sites. I want to show these links on our intranet portal, which is on another web application.

I would prefer search, but the query for that might be a little tricky because I want to show the personal links for the logged in user.

What is the easiest way to do that ?

We are using SharePoint 2013 On-Premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a web part that you can use to do this built into SharePoint.  It shows up as an option in the My Site web application but you can export the web part from there and then import it into your Intranet site.  It will by default show only the links for the logged in user.

The easiest way to get the web part is to go to the web part gallery in your My Site root site collection: `{your mysite base url}/_catalogs/wp/Forms/AllItems.aspx`, then find the quicklinks.dwp web part, edit properties, and click the *Export button*.

This should export a `.dwp` file which you can then upload as a web part on your intranet page. That should be all you need!